# How to include emoji's in utf8mb4_general_ci coded DB? (MySQL issue)

Tags: mysql, database, emoji, navicat

I'm trying via various DB software (Navicat, MySQL Workbench and others) to include an emoji in the table row along with text. The table is utf8mb4_general_ci, so it should work, but it ends up showing as ???? or ?. What is the trick here to include the emoji icons directly?

Comment: Do You have font with emoji? Could you `SELECT HEX(string_with_emoji)...` and show output?

Comment: Does the emoji need additional file to be displayed? Like any webfont?

Answer (score 1):

The versions of navicat < 11.1 don't work.

Use the newest version of Navicat and go to Edit Connection > Advanced > Encoding and Select 65001 (UTF-8). (This enables to you to insert emojis on the database, try copy/paste from web.whatsapp.com for testing) You will see empty Squares.

Then go to tools > grid font > Segoe UI Symbol (this will show only a utf-7 emojis)